# Google Chrome User History

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I opened chrome web browser on my home desktop PC. I have two "persons", my personal user and also my work user when occasionally I work from my home desktop.

After opening my personal user chrome, I searched a lyric from a song that contained a explicit word. When the search went through my work Google was signed into the google website but not the overall browser as if I may have signed into my google work email account through my personal user's browser. So it showed my work email address signed into Google.com, while the overall browser was "paused" on my personal account.

I am somewhat worried it will look like I searched this lyric on my work computer even though it was completely on my home desktop.

So when returning to my work laptop I checked my work history which cannot be deleted. It doesn't look like that search saved into my history my work account through my personal chrome browser but I am kind of worried.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking. It seems you're saying everything is working exactly as you'd expect, but you're worried about something. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear. However, also note, this is your personal browser on your personal computer at your home. If your work has a problem with you accidentally being in the "wrong" user session that's their own fault for how they have you working.

Comment: Thanks for quickly getting back. I reworded it. Does it make more sense?